# Language of midrash?

Tags: hebrew, midrash

What Hebrew did Louis Ginzberg learn to translate the midrashim? In his famous book, is there a dictionary for midrashic words and a midrashic grammar, or is modern Hebrew enough?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Myriam and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 3):

Modern Hebrew wouldn't be enough. There isn't a Mishnaic Hebrew-English dictionary, but Jastrow's Talmudic Aramaic-English dictionary, Bar-Asher's Mishnaic dictionary (תורת הצורות של לשון המשנה), and Segal's *Mishnaic Hebrew Grammar* are great resources. Ginzberg also quotes sources like Josephus, Philo, and apocryphal texts for which you'd need Greek.